# Reaction Role Panel Stops working after a bot restart Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

I have a working reaction role menu that assigns and takes away roles fine until the bot restarts then it stop giving/taking away the roles, I am struggling to find a solution that matches with the way this reaction menu works.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>  {
             if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot)
            if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    
    
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
              if (reaction.emoji.name === reactone){
                
                  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(roleone);
              }
              if (reaction.emoji.name === reacttwo){
                
                  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(roletwo);
              }
              if (reaction.emoji.name === reactthree){
                
                  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(rolethree);
              }
              if (reaction.emoji.name === reactfour){
                
                  await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(rolefour);
              }
              //add more here
            } else{
              return
            }
            });
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Try doing some debugging; put `console.log` statements in various parts of this code (e.g. at the top of the event handler, after each of the `if` condition checks, before and after each role assignment) and see how far your code gets. Doing this will show you what part of your code is the issue, or if your code is being executed at all.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with caching

Comment: I cannot see any errors coming up and it works fine until the bot restarts, I also think its something to do with caching however I am struggling to see where I need to fix/edit to ensure it caches properly

Answer (score 1):

The client is not receiving the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event from messages that were sent before the restart. You need to fetch these messages to be able to receive the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) from these messages.

There's an event called [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) which will be executed when the startup is completed. That's the perfect place to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch) these messages by using the following code:

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID'); # Channel ID where the msg was sent
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 });
```

or if you know the [`message ID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=id):

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID'); # Channel ID where the msg was sent
channel.messages.fetch({ around: MESSAGE_ID, limit: 1 });
```

Read more on the [official discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: thanks for the answer however I cant seem to get this to work for me
have put it inside the client.on("ready", () => {here} is this correct or the wrong place?